# Why don't use msg in printing instead of msg[pointer -1]?

Tags: c, function, printf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

It is printing correctly but I have confusion that whenever I write just **msg**, it gives me **Your ?@** and whenever I write msg[option-1], it gives me full message of **Your name is bilal**. I am not understanding the cause of [option-1]. Why it is used and what is it's function?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#define MAX_LEN 256

int main(){
  FILE * fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
  int option;
  char word[MAX_LEN];
  static const char * const msg[] = {
    "Name",
    "Date of Birth",
    "ID Card Number",
    "Phone Number",
    "Address",
    "Account", 
    "Fixing Year",
    "Amount" };
      for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
      printf("%d. Your %s:\n", option, msg[option-1]);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry bro your code is giving me segmentation fault

Comment: The `%s` format expects a single string (of type `char *`). The array `msg` is an array of strings, it's type is `const char * const[8]`. Why would you expect to be able to use the array `msg` for the `%s` format?

Comment: The code posted works correct. Vlad explains why.

Comment: Ergo debatable way to use `for(option=1;option<=sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *);++option)`, instead of `for(option=0;option<=sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *)-1;++option)`, where the expression here is clearly a constant value computed at compile time, and introducing the term `option-1` in the loop that eventually could not be optimized on not so smart compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%s` is designed to output strings. It expects an argument of the type `char *`.

The array `msg` is declared like

```
static const char * const msg[] = {
//...
```

that is its elements have the type `char *`. The array itself used in expressions has the type `char **`. So it may be supplied to the conversion  specifier `%s`.

The valid range of indices to access elements of the array is `[ 0, sizeod( msg ) / sizeof( char * ) )` while in the loop shown below the index variable is changed from `[1, sizeof( msg ) / sizeod( char * ) + 1 )`.

That is in this loop

```
  for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
```

indices start fro 1. So to output correctly an element of the array you have to use the expression `option - 1` as an index and the expression msg[option-1] has the required type `char *` that is expected by the conversion specifier of the call of prontf.

```
  printf("%d. Your %s:\n", option, msg[option-1]);
```

That is the selected from the array string is outputted.

Comment: I still didn't understand the [option-1]

Comment: @natashaBibi The first element of the array msg has the index 0. Is it clear? How to output this element if the variable option used as an index starts from 1? Or how to output the last element of the array if the variable option is equal to the size of the array? I showed you teh valie range of iondices.

Comment: So in my understanding is it working like this [option-1] == [8-1] then [7-1] and this repeats until it reaches the first one. Means it is going in reverse.

Comment: @natashaBibi You array has 8 elements. The valid indices to access the elements are 0-7 inclusively. The variable option starts from the initial value equal to 1 and is changed up to 8. So to output the first element or the last of the array with the index 0 you have to write msg[oprion-1].

Comment: I understood the first element but what do you mean by the last of the array with the index zero. Is it on reverse?

Comment: @natashaBibi The last value of option used in the loop is equal to teh size of the array that is equal to 8 due to using the relational operator <= in the expression option <= sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *). There is no element with the index 8 in tehharray. The valid range iof indices is 0-7. So to output the whole array you have to use the expression option - 1. In this case it will be changed from 0 to 7 as it is required.

Comment: option starts from 1, option = 1 so in a loop from 0-7, [option-1] will be like this 1-1=0 then 2-1=1 then 3-1=0 then go until 8-1=7 right?